# button control php page include

Tags: php, javascript, include

**because of considering embed google ads into include page. I am giving up `jquery.loading`**

(google not allow jquery ajax and jquery loading for ads, now even iframe page)

so is it possible use other `javascript` method for control php page include?

more explain, if my page need to including 10 pages, and I do not want they all loading in same time(such slowly for loading at same time). So I put 10 buttons for switching include page.

**only click each button, loading the chosen include page to main. and click another one, loading the new one and hidden the first one**.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are links google should crawl them fine, you just need to stop the link from being clicked on in javascript...

```
<a href="test.html" class="test">Test Page</a>
```

Then your jquery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.test').click(function(e){

        // Load the AJAX here

        // Stop the click from actually going to the page
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: just use `e.preventDefault();`, can `embed google ads` in `loading page`? waiting another answer's option.